# Get data from string of specific values SQL

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, select

I'm rather new at SQL programming, and still struggling with the basics. I need to extract some specific rows, from a specified string of IDs.

```
ID  Product City
1   Apple   London
2   Banana  Berlin
3   Orange  Berlin
4   Orange  Paris
5   Apple   Paris
6   Banana  Copenhagen
7   Banana  Copenhagen
8   Banana  London
9   Apple   Paris
10  Orange  London
11  Apple   Berlin
12  Apple   Copenhagen
13  Apple   Paris
```

If I need to select ID=1,2,5,6,10,11,13 how do I extract these specific rows from the database?
I'm using SQLite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `in` clause

```
select * from your_table 
where id in (1,2,5,6,10,11,13)
```

Comment: What if for example I need to select 1500 IDs and these are the top 1500 entries in the database?

Comment: the  top base on an order by?

Comment: @Artem . . . Then you should ask another question.  This answer is the correct answer to this question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks ... is correct..  .... Artem you should mark this answer as accepted and post another question with the new info

Comment: @scaisEdge - wasn't allowed to before now. Hereby done